# BigDecimal and Money

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I've researched and found that when dealing with currency, the best way to go about doing calculations is by the `BigDecimal` class.

With that in mind, I'm working on a code that converts various types of foreign currency into US currency and vice-versa  (specifically, a cashregister that takes foreign currency and converts it into US money, computes the change and returns this amount to the customer in foreign currency).

As of now, many of the methods use `double` and two of them take in `int` as a parameter to be used in computing the US currency.

**Question:**

Since I want to use the BigDecimal class in my calculations, should I change all my methods that make calculations involving doubles to a BigDecimal?

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a great idea. 1+ for wanting to avoid use of floating-point numbers for this.

Comment: Another practical approach for calculating with money is rationals. They have 'unlimited' precision, are stable and also faster than BigDecimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should change all floats or doubles to take either ints, longs or `BigDecimals`.

Floats and doubles are not precise for financial calculations. It's a very good idea to use the [`Money`](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html) pattern to deal with amounts and currencies (it's a special type of [`Quantity`](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/quantity.html)). To maintain a list of moneys possibly in multiple currencies, what you're effectively doing is a `MoneyBag`, a collection of `Money` that can then sum all values given a target currency and a `CurrencyExchangeService` (currency conversion rates should also be stored as `BigDecimals`).

Rounding should be done after every operation according to the number of desired decimal places and the rounding algorithm. The number of decimal places is normally a property of the `Currency` (look, e.g., at [ISO 4217](http://www.currency-iso.org/iso_index/iso_tables/iso_tables_a1.htm)); unless a different number is desired (like when pricing gasoline, for example).

You should definitely look at Fowler's examples; but I've also created a very simple uni-currency [`Money`](https://github.com/codecrafter/orders/blob/master/src/main/java/codecrafter/orders/Money.java) class for an [exercise](http://codecrafter.blogspot.ca/2012/03/some-oo-design.html). It uses dollars only and rounds to 2 decimal places; but it's still a good base for future extensions.

Comment: Sometimes financial calculations take even more sophisticated approaches. E.g. a typical case is separating a an amount into n% and (100-n)% parts so that the sum of the parts is penny-perfect, despite rounding.

Comment: @9000: Yes, Fowler described an allocation algorithm for that, look at PoEAA; I've also used it before with great success...

Comment: @9000: I found the algorithm [here](http://books.google.ca/books?id=Jl5rkQnbfAIC&lpg=PA489&ots=gut4bQs6FR&dq=fowler%20money%20conundrum&pg=PA494#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: ^^Thats Jordao and 9000, I figured I would need to use just BigDecimal.

Comment: @Wormhole99: so, you have multiple currencies but still won't create a `Money` class? You should _strongly_ consider it. The abstraction will make your program easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, BigDecimal is certainly the correct way (floating point almost never). Also in JDBC.

But having said that, there is an issue with rounding. In some cases 6 decimals are legally required in european software. In general you will want to round on 2 places in every step. If you have a quantity with 2 decimals and a price, you'll get 4 decimals, and have to round. So to make the ugly BigDecimal interface even uglier, you probably need some help functions (multiplyRounded?).